# Android - Append Specfic Line In A Text File

Tags: java, android

hey people,
I have a text file which I need to append in my app.  Now I could rewrite the entire file incorporating the changes to a specific line but I'm hoping there is a more efficient solution.
I know the line number I need to append however I'm unsure how to get to that line, preferably without looping through all of the others unless that is the only way.  This is what I have so far which recreates the entire file:`

```
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("tasklist.txt", MODE_APPEND);
            BufferedOutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(buf);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            for(int count = 0; count < str.size(); count++)
            {
                writer.write(str[count]);
                writer.write("\r\n");
            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving txt file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }`
```

Hopefully someone knows of a more efficient solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are some cleaner ways, but with file handling there isn't really a more efficient way (that I know of). You basically go from start to finish, as you have done, and append data. That's how file I/O works (it's not an Android or Java thing).

Still, you could try FileWriter to tidy it up a bit (the "true" param to the ctor means append):

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(aFile, true));
try {
    writer.write("append here\n");
} finally {
   writer.close();
}
```

Be advised though, FileWriter uses the systems default encoding. This should be fine on Android, but be careful with it in general.

Here are some good general [practices for dealing with reading and writing files with Java](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42).

Also, depending on what you're doing with this file you're appending to (how often you are editing the same file, and from what processes), you may need to make a copy of it, and or [deal with fysnc](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html), to make sure you don't lose data on Android devices that use journaling filesystems.

To make your app more efficient though, maybe you could cache data in memory, and only write out the entire file (rather than append), at certain intervals, or when you're done. If you have a lot of data, a DB might even be appropriate.